# How to connect to SqlAzure with Ssmse Error 208

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a database on SqlAzure and i can use it in my project as well. But i want to control database in ssmse . i have this 208 error. i have connection string and username and a password to sign in but they aren't work.

http://c1207.hizliresim.com/z/2/9554j.jpg -- The Error!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using Management Studio Express from 2008 or 2008 R2.

You may wish to try a newer version (e.g. [SQL Server 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062)). The file you want is SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe (assuming 64-bit, else replace x64 with x86).

Answer (score 0):

Use `SSMS 2008 R2 SP1`, I also faced that same problem and solved after using sp1